# Using uu-parsinglib to parse a sequence of Word8s

Tags: haskell, uu-parsinglib

I'm trying to use uu-parsinglib to operate on `[Word8]` rather than [Char].
(I want to use uu-parsinglib for the error reporting.)
I need a parser that will fetch me the next `Word8` in the sequence, whatever it is.
Once I have that, I can build more complex parsers.
But I'm having trouble figuring out how to write it.
The closest I've been able to get is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Data.Word
import Text.ParserCombinators.UU.BasicInstances

pRawWord8 :: Parser Word8
pRawWord8 = pSatisfy (const True) (Insertion undefined undefined undefined)
```

However, that implementation apparently returns the wrong type.

```
amy2.hs:10:13:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘Word8’
    Expected type: Text.ParserCombinators.UU.Core.P
                     (Str Char state loc) Word8
      Actual type: Text.ParserCombinators.UU.Core.P
                     (Str Char state loc) Char
    In the expression:
      pSatisfy (const True) (Insertion undefined undefined undefined)
    In an equation for ‘pRawWord8’:
        pRawWord8
          = pSatisfy (const True) (Insertion undefined undefined undefined)
```

This surprises me, because I don't see how the type signature for `pSatisfy` is restricting me to returning a `Char` instead of a `Word8`.

How can I implement `pRawWord8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pSatisfy has type:

```
pSatisfy :: forall loc state a. (Show a, loc `IsLocationUpdatedBy` a, ListLike state a) => (a -> Bool) -> Insertion a -> P (Str a state loc) a
```

So the Parser returns the same type as the input (`a`). Since Parser is

```
type Parser a = (IsLocationUpdatedBy loc Char, ListLike state Char) => P (Str Char state loc) a
```

The input to Parser is a ListLike of Char, and hence pSatisfy can only return a Parser Char. So the types do forbid what you're trying to do.

Maybe you should type your function as something like

```
pRawWord8 :: (IsLocationUpdatedBy loc Word8, ListLike state Word8) => P (Str Word8 state loc) Word8
```

Or define your own type synonym along these lines.

Comment: Thank you, those types make much more sense now!